# Write dataframe to multiple tabs in a excel sheet using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-excel

I have been using Spark-excel (https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) to write the output to a single sheet of an Excel sheet. However, I am unable to write the output to different sheets (tabs).

Can anyone suggest any alternative?

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Can't you just split your data into several tables and save each other separately while specifying a different `sheetName` parameter?

Comment: I tried that.The data gets overwritten since this supports only overwrite in the save mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to split the problem into two phases:

1. save the data into multiple csv using multiple Spark flows
2. write an application, that converts multiple csv files to a single excel sheet, using e.g. this Java library: http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I will try that out and will let you know.